# Next.JS + SWR: how to handle network error properly?

Tags: typescript, next.js, axios, swr

Quick disclaimer, I'm new to SWR (and Next.JS).

I'm having some "network" issues since I integrated SWR within my Next.JS app.
Randomly, I get network errors on my Chrome console like "ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED" that get triggered. My hook get triggered as well and will have the non-null error object.
The initial call works just fine, it mostly happens when I come back to the page but it's not really "predictable" unfortunately.

The sequence would be: load page > page loaded, display fine > change tab > come back (SWR refresh the cache) > error showing (because of ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED).

**Here is some code if that helps:**

I'm fetching data using this hook

```
export const useGetItemById = (itemId: string) => {
  const { data, error, isLoading, mutate } = useSWR<Item>(
    `/items/${itemId}`,
    fetcher
  );

  return {
    item: data,
    isLoading,
    error,
    mutate,
  };
};
```

My component looks like this

```
export default function ItemDetail({ itemId }: Props) {
  const {
    item,
    isLoading,
    error,
  } = useGetItemById(itemId);

  let content: React.ReactNode | undefined;
  if (isLoading) {
    content = 'loading...';
  } else if (error) {
    content = 'error';
  } else if (item) {
    content = 'content'
  }

  return content;
}
```

How would you guys handle this error? Ideally, I'd like to ignore the error and keep the page as is, since the data is showing fine.

Thank you !

Cheers,